# Rails undefined method error (ONLY in development)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, development-environment, production-environment, nomethoderror

The error I'm getting is in my partial _pins.html.erb:

NoMethodError in Pins#index 
-- undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #4):

```
3:      <div class="avatar-position">
4:          <%= image_tag pin.user.avatar.url(:thumb), class: "thumbsize" %>
5:      </div>
```

The pins/index view (index.html.erb) has `<%= render @pins %>`

I am rendering this via the index controller, so in pins_controller.rb I have:

```
  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pins }
    end
  end
```

The weird thing is it works fine in production. When I push to heroku, I get no errors and everything renders fine. I did recently update my Mac OSX to 10.8.5, but I am not if that was the culprit? One thing that is different is that in development, my image assets (avatars) are saved locally, while in production they are saved on amazons AWS with paperclip... Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that there is no user record associated to pin in line 4.

Comment: what is the local variable `pin` here ? in  `<%= image_tag pin.user.avatar.url(:thumb), class: "thumbsize" %>` and some of the `pin` has no user so you got `avatar' for nil:NilClass` as `pin.user` is `nil`

Comment: I tried restarting the local server, and restarting my computer, no luck.

Comment: every user has many pins - I am basically trying to get the stored avatar of the user by identifying the user by his pin id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the local variable `pin` here ? in `<%= image_tag pin.user.avatar.url(:thumb), class: "thumbsize" %>` and some of the `pin has no user` so you got`avatar' for nil:NilClass` as `pin.user` is `nil`

so make it

```
<%= image_tag pin.user.avatar.url(:thumb), class: "thumbsize"  unless pin.user.nil? %>
```

Comment: You are a rock star, that worked!  I guess the problem was that in my development database, there were some users who did not have an avatar... which explains why it was working in production where all avatars were there.